# Array "maximum difference" algorithm that runs in O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given an array of N integers, sort the array, and find the 2 consecutive numbers in the sorted array with the maximum difference.

Example – on input `[1,7,3,2]` output `4` (the sorted array is `[1,2,3,7]`, and the maximum difference is 7-3=4).

Algorithm A runs in `O(NlogN)` time.

I need to find an algorithm identical in function to algorithm A, that runs in O(N) time.

Comment: And what paths have you explored so far?

Comment: You just need to return the maximum difference, right?  You don't have to return the sorted array as well?

Comment: Counting and Radix sorts might give you O(n). From there you can easily figure out the max diff using an O(n) algorithm. O(n) + O(n) = O(n).

Comment: Yes, I only need maximum difference. Integer sizes are not limited, so Counting/Radix this time wont work

Comment: Linear time algorithm explained here http://www.zrzahid.com/the-%E2%80%A9maximum%E2%80%A9-gap%E2%80%A9-problem-%E2%80%A9pigeonhole-%E2%80%A9principle%E2%80%A9/

Comment: @OJ. Radix/Counting sort's complexity is O(input_size + range). You'll get O(n) only when the range <= input_size. What if the range exceeds n? Example: `[1,9,2]`. Here Radix or Counting sort is not the right approach.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let the array be X and let n = length(X). Put each element x in bucket number floor((x - min(X)) * (n - 1) / (max(X) - min(X))). The width of each bucket is (max(X) - min(X))/(n - 1) and the maximum adjacent difference is at least that much, so the numbers in question wind up in different buckets. Now all we have to do is consider the pairs where one is the max in bucket i and the other is the min in bucket j where i < j and all buckets k in (i, j) are empty. This is linear time.

Proof that we really need floor: let the function be f(X). If we could compute f(X) in linear time, then surely we could decide in linear time whether

0 < f(X) ≤ (max(X) - min(X))/(length(X) - 1),

i.e., whether the elements of X are evenly spaced and not all identical. Let this predicate be P(X). The support of P has factorial(length(X)) connected components, so the usual Ω(n log n) lower bounds for algebraic models of computation apply.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I wanted to understand the last statement 


_Let this predicate be P(X). The support of P has factorial(length(X)) connected components, so the usual Ω(n log n) lower bounds for algebraic models of computation apply.better_


I struggle with problems unless I establish rules for invariants and I feel this might help me explaining this problem better, even though I intuitively understand "how" its working

Comment: You also have to consider the pairs `(min(X), min(B[0]))` and `(max(X), max(B[n-2]))` if `B[0...n-2]` are the `n-1` buckets.

Comment: What if no bucket is empty? Then {k | k∈(i,j) and size(k) = 0} = ∅. What do we do then?

Answer (score 4):

Execute a [*Counting Sort*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Counting_sort) and then scan the result for the largest difference.

Because of the consecutive number requirement, at first glance it seems like any solution will require sorting, and this means at best O(*n* log *n*) unless your number range is sufficiently constrained for a Counting Sort. But if it is, you win with O(*n*).

Comment: As OJ points out, a radix sort should also work.  I've always liked radix sort but unfortunately most problems seem to involve character data...

Comment: Yes, in normal real-life situation it would work, but in this task integer range isn't limited. I suppose it can be done without sorting at all.

Comment: It is always O(n), check my solution.

Comment: `at first glance it seems like any solution will require sorting` maybe, but at closer inspection, that doesn't hold.

Answer (score 0):

Now, first try to think if you were already given the minimum value `MIN` and maximum value `MAX` in the `array` of `size N`, under what circumstances would the max gap be minimum and maximum ?

Obviously, maximum gap will be maximum when all elements are either `MIN` or `MAX` making `maxgap = MAX - MIN`.

Maximum gap will be minimum when all the elements are equally spaced apart between `MIN` and `MAX`. Lets say the spacing between them is gap.

So, they are arranged as

```
MIN, MIN + gap, MIN + 2*gap, MIN + 3*gap, ... MIN + (N-1)*gap 
where

MIN + (N-1)*gap = MAX .

gap = (MAX - MIN) / (N - 1).
```

So, we know now that our answer will lie in the `range [gap, MAX - MIN]`. 
Now, if we know the answer is more than gap, what we do is create buckets of size gap for ranges .

```
[MIN, MIN + gap), [Min + gap, `MIN` + 2* gap) ... and so on
```

There will only be `(N-1)` such buckets. We place the numbers in these buckets based on their value.

If you pick any 2 numbers from a single bucket, their difference will be less than gap, and hence they would never contribute to `maxgap` ( Remember `maxgap >= gap` ). We only need to store the largest number and the smallest number in each bucket, and we only look at the numbers across bucket.

Now, we just need to go through the bucket sequentially ( they are
already sorted by value ), and get the difference of min_value with
max_value of previous bucket with at least one value. We take maximum of all such values.

```
int maximumGap(const vector<int> &num) {
    if (num.empty() || num.size() < 2) return 0;

    int maxNum = *max_element(num.begin(), num.end());
    int minNum = *min_element(num.begin(), num.end());

    //average gap from minNum to maxNum.
    int gap = (maxNum - minNum - 1) / (num.size() - 1) + 1;

    //number of buckets = num.size() - 1
    vector<int> bucketsMin(num.size() - 1, INT_MAX);
    vector<int> bucketsMax(num.size() - 1, INT_MIN);

    //put into buckets
    for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++) 
    {
        if (num[i] != maxNum && num[i] != minNum)
        {
            int buckInd = (num[i] - minNum) / gap;
            bucketsMin[buckInd] = min(bucketsMin[buckInd], num[i]);
            bucketsMax[buckInd] = max(bucketsMax[buckInd], num[i]);
        }
    }
    int maxGap = INT_MIN;
    int previous = minNum;

    for (int i = 0; i < num.size() - 1; i++) 
    {
        if (bucketsMin[i] == INT_MAX && bucketsMax[i] == INT_MIN) continue;   //empty
        //i_th gap is minvalue in i+1_th bucket minus maxvalue in i_th bucket
        maxGap = max(maxGap, bucketsMin[i] - previous);
        previous = bucketsMax[i];
    }
    maxGap = max(maxGap, maxNum - previous);
    return maxGap;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Find minimum and maximum
2. Pick a random number `k` from the array
3. Sort the algorithm by placing all the values smaller than `k` to the left and larger than `k` to the right.
4. You know the minimum and the maximum of both of the groups, calculate the gape of the left group assuming that the values are on a strait line. Do the same for the right group.
5. Go to 2 with the group that got the bigger gape, you know the min and max of that group. Do this until the selected group got no more than 4 values.
6. You got now a group with only 4 elements, sort and find the solution.

Here is an example of how this algorithm works:

- Input: 9 5 3 4 12 9 31 17
- Pick random number: k = 9
- Sort by smaller and bigger values of k
- 5 3 4 9 9 12 31 17, k is in index 3
- Left group gape = (9 + 3) / (4 - 1) = 4
- Right group gape = (31 + 9) / (5 - 1) = 10
- We pick the right group 9 9 12 31 17
- Pick random number: k = 12
- Sort by smaller and bigger values of k
- 9 9 12 31 17, k is in index 2
- Left group gape = (12 + 9) / (3 - 1) = 11.5
- Right group gape = (31 + 12) / (3 - 1) = 21.5
- The maximum gape in 12 31 17 is 31 - 17 = 14

My algorithm is very similar to [Selection Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) for finding the k index value of sorted algorithm in linear time.

Comment: The algorithm seems very unintuitive and difficult to grasp logically. Can you please elaborate on your thought process/ inspiration behind the approach?

Comment: doesn't work. `[-8, 8, 9,10,11,12,13,14]`. We select 9 randomly, and up with the same array, divided at 9, where 9 belongs to the right side. left "gape" is 0, which is smaller than the right "gape", (14+9)/5=5. we select the right group, and will never find the requested largest gap between -8 and 8.

Comment: Why would the biggest gap be in the half with the bigger average gap?