# find maximum difference between successive elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an unsorted array (all elements are non-negative integers), find the maximum difference between the successive elements in its sorted form.

How can I solve it without sorting the array? Sorting seems does redundant work. May be there is a O(n) solution?

Comment: Is this a homework exercise -- in other words, do you know a solution exists? Because I don't see how you could do this without sorting, either explicitly or implicitly -- to know which elements are "successive", you will have to order them.

Comment: http://fenghaolw.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/maximum-gap.html

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10262937/2170192

Comment: If you know the range of the values (and it's not particularly too large), then you can sort the array in `O(n)`.